# protect from XSS (ideal function)?

Tags: php, antixsslibrary

```
function xap ($in, $format=false) {
   if ($format == 'html') {
      //Делаем безопасный html
   $in = preg_replace('/(<(link|script|iframe|object|applet|embed).*?>[^<]*(<\/(link|script|iframe|object|applet|embed).*?>)?)/i', '', $in); //Удаляем стили, скрипты, фреймы и flash
  $in = preg_replace('/(script:)|(expression\()/i', '\\1&nbsp;', $in); //Обезвреживаем скрипты, что остались
  $in = preg_replace('/(onblur|onchange|onclick|ondblclick|onfocus|onkeydown|onkeypress|onkeyup|onload|onmousedown|onmousemove|onmouseout|onmouseover|onmouseup|onreset|onselect|onsubmit|onunload)=?/i', '', $in);
  $in = preg_replace('/((src|href).*?=.*?)(http:\/\/)/i', '\\1redirect/\\2', $in); 
  return $in;
} else {
  return htmlentities($in);
    }
}
echo xap($text); //for read
echo xap($text, "html"); //for read html tags
```

Author say that this is ideal code for protect from XSS... is it true?

Comment: There's no such thing as "ideal code". There are tons of nasty ways to circumvent such XSS filters, including abusing little-known encodings such as UTF-7. I'd look for a publicly documented, well-known, peer-reviewed library instead of trusting a single author to provide the "ideal code".

Answer (score 0):

`htmlentities()` will protect you against XSS.

You code looks like you also want to allow some HTML code. You should still run `htmlentities()` and after this run `str_replace()` to allow some html tags you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Should be safe enough

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten onerror. => 
`<img src="http://idontexists.neke/notexists.jpg" onerror="alert(document.cookie)" />`